# Why isn't my python programm converging to pi?

Tags: python, random, statistics, pi

I wrote this method:

```
def approx_pi(n, p):
    """
    Approximates Pi by putting dots in a square and counting
    the dots in the max possible circle in that square.
    :param n: Number of dots
    :param p: Precision used for urandom
    :return: Approximation of Pi
    """
    in_circle = 0
    k = 100
    max_int = (2**(8*p)-1)
    for i in range(n):
        # get two random Numbers between 0 and 1
        x = int.from_bytes(os.urandom(p), byteorder='big')/max_int
        y = int.from_bytes(os.urandom(p), byteorder='big')/max_int

        if x ** 2 + y ** 2 <= 1:
            in_circle += 1

        # Just for debugging
        if (i+1) % k == 0:
            k = int(k*1.01)
            print(i, '\t',4*in_circle/i)
            sys.stdout.flush()

    return 4*in_circle/n
```

In most of my Testruns, it is getting stable at 3.141 and then diverges around that value.
Is this a weakness of urandom? But if so, why isn't pi shifting in one direction? Or is there something wrong with my code.

Comment: Does it work if you use `x = int.from_bytes(os.urandom(p), byteorder='big')` (`y` analog) and `if x ** 2 + y ** 2 <= max_int**2` ? Just to chancel out non-precise floating point operations.

Comment: What are your values for `n` and `p`?

Comment: @Stefan, I choose n := 1.000.000.000 and p \in {1, 2, 3, 4}.

Comment: @koffein thats really a good point! Unfortunately it seems to have no effect so far, but I am increasing Numbers and do more testing.

Comment: Regarding convergence, you should expect to see a relative error of 1/sqrt(*n*) if you sample *n* points. So if you sample a million points, your error will be in the range of 0.003. A trillion points, and your error is about 0.000003.

Comment: @koffein that did the trick. I am getting now as close as I like ;-)

Comment: @Finn One more thing: There are no benefits in choosing `n>max_int**2`, because in those cases you could also take every possible `(x,y)`-combination and you would get a better outcome.

Answer (score 2):

First of all. Your code is very confusing. It is better if you call the variables by a name that give you an idea about what they mean.

I have simplified the code to the necessary lines. Hence, I use random library for generating the points position.

The problem with this method is that it converges very slowly. With 10**8 points i got 3.14167604.

```
import random


def approx_pi(points):
    """
    Approximates Pi by putting dots in a square and counting
    the dots in the max possible circle in that square.
    :param points: Number of dots
    :return: Approximation of Pi
    """
    in_circle = 0
    for dummy_i in xrange(points):
        # get two random Numbers between 0 and 1
        x_dot_position = random.random()
        y_dot_position = random.random()

        if x_dot_position ** 2 + y_dot_position ** 2 <= 1:
            in_circle += 1

    return 4.0*in_circle/points
```

**EDITING**
You were rigth about the function random.random(). So in the next code I have used random.random_integers which is a uniform distribution between [low, high] values.

The code is parallelized and i tried for 10**10 points getting:

PI = 3.14157765
Tiempo de calculo = 3790 seconds

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import numpy as np

starting_point = time.time()

def approx_pi(point):
    """
    Approximates Pi by putting dots in a square and counting
    the dots in the max possible circle in that square.
    :param points: Number of dots
    :return: Approximation of Pi
    """
    # get two random Numbers between 0 and 1
    x_dot_position = float(np.random.random_integers(0,10**10))/10**10
    y_dot_position = float(np.random.random_integers(0,10**10))/10**10

    if x_dot_position ** 2 + y_dot_position ** 2 <= 1:
        return 1
    else: 
        return 0

###########################################################

total_points     = 1*10**10       
paso    = 1*10**8       

in_circle = 0

for in_este_bucle in xrange(0, total_points, paso):
    print "Procesadores disponibles: " + str(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    resultado = pool.map(approx_pi, xrange(in_este_bucle, in_este_bucle + paso))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    in_circle += sum(resultado)
    del resultado


print 'Total time: ' + str(time.time()-starting_point) +' seconds'
print
print 4.0*in_circle/total_points
```

Comment: Thanks. I think we should not use `random.random()` the main thing is, that the returned values are in `[0, 1)` so we will get a pi' > pi. And according to the python docs its saver to use `os.urandom()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're starting to dabble in Monte Carlo methods. When using Monte Carlo methods the random numbers you generate must have a uniform distribution to yield an accurate approximation. Try using:

```
import random

random.uniform(0,1)
```

This should yield better results. ivangtorre is absolutely right that a large sample size is needed for an accurate approximation. Here's a link to Monte Carlo methods on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method The introduction section of this article talks about exactly what you're working on now. Cheers.

Edit: You could also increase the range of random.uniform(0,1) and then adjust your algorithm accordingly to get a slight increase in performance.